# Connect to FileSite and open file

Tags: vbscript, autonomy, imanage

I'm just starting as an analyst/programmer for a firm and working on code to save all open files before a reboot, then restore/open those files after the next startup.

I'm struggling with our DMS, FileSite, and so far haven't had any luck in tracking down the support documentation or figuring out our customer service relationship.

I've done all my coding in VBScript so far, though I'm open to converting to VB or C#. I'm starting to suspect that VBScript just isn't the right tool for this, but because [insert uninteresting details here], I'm temporarily stuck with VBScript. Any answers that don't include switching languages just yet would be greatly appreciated. But if you do know for sure that I can't do what I want in VBScript, that would also be really helpful info.

I need to do the following:

- Connect to FileSite
- Open a file (whose name I already know)

I've looked at sample code online, but without the support documentation I'm having trouble making sense of it. I try to modify and run the code and get errors like "ActiveX can't create object: 'iManage.NRTDMS'", and "Class not defined: 'IManage'".

A couple discussions suggested running regsvr32 on the libraries, but that throws an incompatibility error.

We do have WorkSite integrated with Outlook, if that makes any difference in the way I need to go about things.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some help from RKnott2 on Autonomy's DevNet. Turns out there's a pretty simple protocol handler for this if you're already connected to FileSite:

```
Function fnOpenFileSite()

    Dim objShell
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    Dim iwlurl
    iwlurl = "iwl:dms=[Server]&lib=[Database]&num=[Doc Number]&ver=[Version Number}&command=opencmd"

 objShell.ShellExecute iwlurl,"","","",1

    Set objShell = Nothing

 End Function
```